# Как перевести текст в месторасположение ячейки

Tags: javascript, json, node.js

Есть вот такой код, и есть определённые ячейки в json. Я записываю в переменные месторасположение ячейки и позже пытаюсь вывести, но вылетает ошибка. Помогите пожалуйста, как из текста перевести в месторасположение файла.

```
   var znak = 'aries';
   var date = 'today';
    request('http://ignio.com/r/export/utf/xml/daily/com.xml', function (error, response, body) {
            var parseString = require('xml2js').parseString;
            parseString(body, function (err, result) {
              var res = result.horo.znak.date;
              console.log(res);
              //выше будет ошибка
              var res = 'result.horo.'+znak+'.'+date;
              //здесь выведется просто текст, а не ячейка с данными
              console.log(res);
            });
          });
        });
```

Comment: `res = result.horo[znak][date]`

Comment: Если undefined, значит, в `result.horo.aries.today` ничего нет